# How to call a function within a function with parameters?

Tags: c, function, parameters, parameter-passing

Trying to call function "TaxInput" within the "PayInput" so my tax and net pay can print with each employee's profile. Instead, it is printing all "tax" and "net pay" after the last employee's output. I've tried calling it inside "PayInput" with parameters but it doesn't compile. if I take the parameters out then it completely skips the function and doesn't print tax nor netPay at all.see below:

```
Pay to: Employee1
Hours worked: 45.00
Hourly rate: $1.00
Gross pay: $52.50
Base pay: $45.00
Overtime pay: $7.50

Pay to: Employee2
Hours worked: 45.00
Hourly rate: $1.00
Gross pay: $52.50
Base pay: $45.00
Overtime pay: $7.50
Taxes paid: $10.50
Taxes paid: $10.50
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PayInput(char empNames[5][32], float empHours[], float empRates[], 
             float overtime[], float overtime_pay[], float gross[],
             float basepay[], float netPay[], float tax[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++) 
    {
        printf("\n\nPay to: %s \n", empNames[i]);
        printf("Hours worked: %.2f \n", empHours[i]);
        printf("Hourly rate: $%.2f \n", empRates[i]);

        if (empHours[i] > 40) 
        {
            overtime[i] = empHours[i] - 40;
            overtime_pay[i] = overtime[i] * (empRates[i] * 1.5);
            printf("Gross pay: $%.2f \n", gross[i] = empHours[i] * 
      empRates[i] + overtime_pay[i]);
            printf("Base pay: $%.2f \n", basepay[i] = empHours[i] 
    * empRates[i]);
            printf("Overtime pay: $%.2f \n", overtime_pay[i]);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Gross income: $%.2f \n", gross[i] = 
    empHours[i] * empRates[i]);
            printf("Base pay: $%.2f \n", basepay[i] = empHours[i] 
    * empRates[i]);
        }
    }
}

void TaxInput(float gross[], float tax[], float netPay[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++)
    {
        tax[i] = gross[i] * 20 / 100;
        printf("Taxes paid: $%.2f \n", tax[i]);

        netPay[i] = gross[i] - tax[i];
        printf("Net Pay: $%.2f \n", netPay[i]);
    }
}

float TotalGross=0;

void allGross(float gross[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++)
    {
        TotalGross += gross[i];
    }
    printf("Total paid to employees: $%.2f", TotalGross);
}   

int main()
{
    char empNames[5][32];
    float empRates[5], empHours[5], overtime[5], overtime_pay[5], 
        gross[5], basepay[5], tax[5], netPay[5];

    NameInput(empNames, empHours, empRates);

    printf("\n\n-------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

    PayInput(empNames, empHours, empRates, overtime, overtime_pay, gross, 
        basepay, tax);

    TaxInput(gross, tax, netPay);

    printf("\n\n");

    allGross(gross);

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: If you're passing that many arguments you *really* need to think about organizing all of that into a singular structure and passing in an array of *N* of those instead. This function is cluttered with inputs. You're also making huge assumptions about the size of character buffers, which is a mistake in most cases. 32 letters may or may not be enough. Use `char*` and dynamic buffers whenever possible.

Comment: I don't see an attempt to call the function. The call would be no different from the other function calls you have in makn6

Comment: `BUFSIZ` (`<stdio.h>`) is also a good option usually.

Comment: tried this but it is still not working. PayInput(empNames, empHours, empRates, overtime, overtime_pay, gross, basepay, tax, netPay, TaxInput (gross, netPay, tax));

Comment: What is `Times`?

Comment: If you try to call `TaxInput()` from within `PayInput()` instead of from `main()`, you have to ensure that you declare (or define) `TaxInput()` before you use it.  You seriously need to learn about structures; this cries out for the use of structures.  The `TotalGross` variable should not be global.  And you should never consider using `float` (and probably not even `double` or `long double`) for real payroll calculations.  A `float` simply doesn't have enough precision to compute $100,000.00 to 2 decimal places.  A `double` has problems with rounding — it can't represent decimals precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is printing all "tax" … after the last employee's output.

Of course it is, since you have now the function `PayInput()` which prints all *Times* pay data in a loop and then the function `TaxInput()` which prints all *Times* tax data in a loop. Given this impractical program structure, the simplest fix is to merge the two functions by deleting the lines

```
    }
}

void TaxInput(float gross[], float tax[], float netPay[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++)
    {
```

and call only

```
    PayInput(empNames, empHours, empRates, overtime, overtime_pay, gross, 
        basepay, netPay, tax);
```

in `main()`.

Apart from that, the commenters' advice about using a structure is quite worthy of consideration.